# Multi-column silverlight repeater?

Tags: silverlight, layout, repeater

It's easy to repeat templated data, using List box, or StackPanel + ItemsControl, etc.  However, I cant figure how to get multiple columns, ie, column alignment.

Example:

Name:  John Doe

Street:  123 st

City:  Seattle

State:  WA

This link below shows the general layout I am trying to programmatically replicate (scroll near bottom):
http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/wpf-silverlight-lob-form-layout-searching-for-a-better-solution/

Obviously, the data (and label) can vary in size.  Also obvious, I could force a fixed width repeating a horizontal stackpanel, but that is lame.

In ASP.NET, you just use a repeater, and get results by repeating a table row + columns.  Since an HTML table respects/adjusts the column sizes for ALL rows, the data will simply line up.  In silverlight, you... do what?

Note:  a datagrid could do this... by why on earth would you want to use that for simple layout of a "form" like this example?

Answer (score 0):

Is the entire pattern above repeating, meaning you have this block of options for each item?  If so, why not just make your ItemTemplate a Grid with the left column fixed width?  If not, can you elaborate more?

Comment: Yes, the entire thing repeats, but not with the same type of data.  My form looks like this (scroll near bottom):
http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/wpf-silverlight-lob-form-layout-searching-for-a-better-solution/

It is built on the fly, i.e., it might have these 4 groups of fields, or it might have 3 or 13.  Each group has its own template and type of data.  And in my case, even within a group like "address", I might have 3 lines for street, or not.  And it would render according to the collection of fields that comes in.